# how to enable textfield to edit using javascript and html?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am getting value on my textfield from the database and it works perfectly fine.

1. I want to create a checkbox, when checkbox click the values comming from database will be clear in textfield and textfiled allow user to enter the new values.
2. If checkbox not clicked then the values comming from the database will be readonly/untouched/disable. Textfield don't allow the user to edit.

I am using this code:

```
<div>
Enter New Details: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="textdis" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
<hr><br>
<label for="full_name">Full Name:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="full_name"  id="full_name" value="<?=$fullname;?>" readonly>
</div>




<!-- // Check Box Functionality For Enter New Address -->
<script>
function myFunction() {
var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
var text = document.getElementById("textdis");
if (checkBox.checked == true){
 text.style.display = "block";

<!-- Here I want If the checkbox is clicked allow the user to enter value in the textfield-->
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="full_name"  id="full_name" disabled="enabled">



} else {
  text.style.display = "none";


<!-- Here I want If the checkbox unclicked take value from the database and don't allow user to edit the textfield-->
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="full_name"  id="full_name" value="<?=$fullname;?>" readonly>


}
}
</script>
```

when checkbox is clicked the textfield not allow to edit.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change "onclick" to "onchange"

```
onchange="myFunction()"
```

Toggle disabled attribute of your input according to the checkbox value

```
function myFunction() {
   var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
   var text = document.getElementById("textdis");
   var field= document.getElementById("full_name");
   if (checkBox.checked == true){
      text.style.display = "block";
      field.disabled=false;
   } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
      field.disabled=true;
   }
}
```

I suggest you to add some server side validation as well in whichever language you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still not working. Textfield doesn't allow the user to edit.

Comment: Hi @Sarah, Edited my answer a little. Kindly check

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you put a disabled state on your text box when the checkbox is not checked and toggle this disabled state onChange of the checkbox.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck"  onChange="myFunction()">
```

JS

```
var nameText = document.getElementById('full_name');
var checkBox = document.getElementById('myCheck');

function myFunction() {

    if (checkBox.checked) {
         nameText.disabled = false;
     } else {
        nameText.disabled = true;
     }
    }
```